# Can you add dynamic content to Introjs step

Tags: intro.js

Is it possible to add content dynamically to a step's tooltip content in Intro.js ?

I am using the callback `onChange` to check which element step we are up to, which works great.  I would also like to be able to add the `textContent` from the element into the tooltip itself if possible, to make the tooltip content more dynamic for the user experience?